# Return data from PHP back to a javascript file?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a comments section on my websites that uses jQuery to animate comments in without reloading the page, as well as deleting comments.

Right now, I have it so when you write a comment, it sends it to a external JS, then to a php file where it processes. If it was successful, it will append the comment into the comment section. My delete action: jQuery deletes my the comment ID in the mysql database.

So my issue is I want to add a delete button via jQuery and somehow call back to the javascript file and tell it the id so the delete button knows the ID to put in the form so the delete file knows what to delete?

Here's my `add_comment` script:

```
$(function() {

$(".commentbutton").click(function() {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myflashpics.com/process_addcomment.php",
  data: $("#commentform").serialize(),
  success: function() {

    var theComment = $("#commentsss").val();
    var theUserId = $("#user_id_two").val();
    var thePhotoId = $("#photo_id").val();
    var theProfilePicture = $("#user_profile_picture").val();
    var theUsername = $("#user_username").val();

    // Get new HTML data
    var html = "<div class='comment_odd'><img src='" + theProfilePicture + "' class='comment_thumbnail'/><div class='comment_username'>" + theUsername + "</div><div class='comment_text'>" + theComment + "</div></div>";

    // Append, then fade in
    $(html).hide().appendTo(thecommentsdisplay).fadeIn(500);

  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

Thanks in advance!
Coulton

**EDIT 1:**

Here's my comments form (just to clarify):

```
user_id_two (the user's ID)
commentsss (comments field)
photo_id (the id of the photo being commented on)
user_profile_picture (profile to display on the user's profile picture in the banner)
user_username (username of the user commenting)
```

Here's also my delete button form:

```
<form method='post' action='' name='deleteform' id='deleteform'>
<input type='hidden' name='userid' value='<?php echo "$userid_session"; ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='userpass' value='<?php echo "$password_session"; ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='pictureid' id='pictureid' value='<?php echo "$picture_id"; ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='profilepictureid' id='profilepictureid' value='<?php echo "$user_profile_picture_id"; ?>' />
</form>
```

And lastly my DELETE COMMENT jQuery:

```
$(function() {

$(".commentdeletebutton").click(function() {

 var className = $(this).attr('class');  
 var theID = className.replace(/delete_button commentdeletebutton delete_(\d+)/, "$1");
 commentDone = "#comment_" + theID;
 formDone = "#commentdeleteform_" + theID;

 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://myflashpics.com/process_deletecomment.php",
  data: $(formDone).serialize(),
  success: function() {

    $(commentDone).hide();

  }
 });
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. First of, there are several IDs, but you don't show us setting/using any. Secondly, your code is all unmatched and confusing.

Comment: Please check my updates.

Comment: Not sure why you need an entire form for deleting, why not a simple link?

Comment: @morgar You don't want a link for deleting; that makes is susceptable to web-crawlers and link cachers. Therefore, itt is best-practice to only do something like a delete from a POST request.

Comment: @morgar: I wanted to do it through jQuery.... Any code samples with just a simple link?

Comment: Ok, but I guess that link will be only visible for logged users, so crawlers couldn't see them.

Comment: I'm doing it with jquery/ajax in the way I mentioned briefly in the answer. Let me check my code.

Comment: @morar: Correct. It only appears if the user is logged in.

Comment: Sorry, I must go off for a while, I will try to post more detailed code later, if anybody else doesn't do it in the while

Comment: @morgar: It's all good. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm here again. Check the new sample. Please be carefull, I didn't test it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an  link for deleting, you can insert the complete url for deleting in the href, i.e. `http://myflashpics.com/process_removecomment.php?id=xx`.
So, you can bind a click event to that link and get the right url using `$(this).attr('href')` and doing the delete using ajax.

Edited for a more complete sample:

```
<? [[Loop your recordset]] { ?>
<div class="comment">
    <a href="http://myflashpics.com/process_deletecomment.php?id=<?=$id?>">Delete</a>
    <div class="comment">
        [[Comment content...]]  
    </div>
</div>
<? } ?>

<script>
$(function() {
    $(".commentdeletebutton").click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('href'),
            success: function(data) {
                $this.parent().slideUp('fast', function() { 
                    $this.parent().remove(); 
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think is a very bad idea to have user/pw visible in your source, you must not do it in that way. You must use user/pw only at the login, after that you only need to keep a session alive.

Comment: This isn't the problem. It works fine. The ID comes from AUTO INCREMENT field in the database. The only way to get the id it to get stuff back from the PHP file processing it... see my problem?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, I guess you insert the new comment in the Db in `process_addcomment.php`. So, you can `echo` the `id` (or any other info you could need to return) and you will get it in the `data` argument of the success function. Once you have it you can set it in the delete link. Ask me if you need more detailed info.

Comment: In a similar case, I return the entire html block (including the delete link with the proper ID), because I render it using a template system. So, the ajax success function only appends it to the page.